# Method Definition in Protocols

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using a Object method inside the @protocol , but protocol only supports method declaration , could someone help me about how to connect that with the method definition of the same method .(where to write the method Definition).

Comment: I think you're confusing a few things here. Do you mean where to put the method *implementation*?

Comment: You may want to read through the [`protocol documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocProtocols.html) to understand how protocols are used.

Comment: Place `@class Object;` above the `@protocol` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols are just a list of method declarations without any implementation. They can be used to restrict a set of possible (classes) to those that implement a certain protocol.

For instance if you had a `GasStation` class you might want to restrict the type (class) of objects that can be refueled at the station. Of course you could simply require the objects to be a descendant of the class `Vehicle`, like this:

```
@interface GasStation : NSObject
- (void)refuel:(Vehicle *)vehicle;
@end

@implementation GasStation 
- (void)refuel:(Vehicle *)vehicle {
    [vehicle addFuel:100];
}
@end
```

But this wouldn't allow a jerrycan to be filled up for instance. However allowing any type of object to be passed is a bad idea either, because if you passed an instance of `Cat` you would certainly get an error when trying to send it an `addFuel:` message.

So instead you define a protocol that refuelable classes have to implement:

```
@protocol RefuelableThing
@required
- (void)addFuel:(float)fuel;
@end
```

Now you can use that protocol to restrict what types of objects can be refueled:

```
@interface GasStation : NSObject
- (void)refuel:(NSObject<RefuelableThing> *)thing;
@end
```

A `Vehicle` will of course have a method `addFuel:` and so can `JerryCan` implement its own separate version, even though it's not a `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare the protocol, any class that conforms to it can implement the methods in that protocol. Just import the header where the protocol is declared, add the protocol to that class's interface and implement the method in the .m  reading up on the topic is an excellent suggestion, btw